# Windows 10 Universal App VB.NET Passing data between pages

Tags: vb.net, xaml, win-universal-app

I have found that navigation between pages in VB.NET is called like this:

```
Frame.Navigate(GetType(MainPage))
```

and from what I have read, you can pass a parameter like this:

```
Frame.Navigate(GetType(MainPage), "Parameter Here!!")
```

The problem is, I cannot get it through to the other page. Finding many examples in C# I see it might be using one of the below methods. Although, none of these seem to be recognised in VS2015

```
 Protected Overrides Sub LoadState(navigationParameter As Object, pageState As Dictionary(Of String, Object))

 Protected Overrides Sub onNavigateTo(**Params**)
```

^^ They both state "...does not have an override a sub in a base class"

How to I receive the parameter in the newly presented page? is it a different method entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging into the Page class which all pages inherit from It seems overriding the "onNavigateTo" Sub is key in this operation. From here you can access its argument and pass through successfully.
Unfortunaly, even Microsoft doesn't provide VB.NET Documentation for this. Here is my code:

In the First page

```
Frame.Navigate(GetType(BlankPage1), "Hello")
```

In the Second Page

```
 Public NotInheritable Class BlankPage1
        Inherits Page
        Public thestring As String

    Protected Overrides Sub onNavigatedTo(e As NavigationEventArgs)
        thestring = e.Parameter

    End Sub
```

This works successfully. I hope this helps people in the future